# TypeError: "x" is not a function Angular typescript method

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have the following code of an entity called Epic, with a method of a class called pendingTasks();

```
import { Solution } from '../solutions.model';
import { PortfolioKanban } from '../kanban/portfolio-kanban.model';
import { Kanbanitem } from '../kanban/kanbanitem';
import { Task, TaskStatus } from '../kanban/Task';

export interface EpicConstructor {
  new (
    id: string,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    code: string,
    entryDate: Date,
    state: string,
    columnID: string,
    kanbanId: string,
    outcome: string,
    owner: string,
    tasks?: Task[]
  ): Epic;
}
export function createEpic(
  ector: EpicConstructor,
  id: string,
  name: string,
  description: string,
  code: string,
  entryDate: Date,
  state: string,
  columnID: string,
  kanbanId: string,
  outcome: string,
  owner: string,
  tasks?: Task[]
) {
  return new ector(
    id,
    name,
    description,
    code,
    entryDate,
    state,
    columnID,
    kanbanId,
    outcome,
    owner,
    tasks
  );
}

export class Epic implements Kanbanitem {
  id: string;
  code: string;
  description;
  entryDate: Date;
  state: string;
  name: string;
  outcome?: string;
  owner: string;
  kanban?: PortfolioKanban;
  kanbanId: string;
  columnId: string;
  tasks?: Task[];

  constructor(
    id: string,
    name: string,
    description: string,
    code: string,
    entryDate: Date,
    state: string,
    columnID: string,
    kanbanId: string,
    outcome: string,
    owner: string,
    tasks?: Task[]
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.entryDate = entryDate;
    this.state = state;
    this.columnId = columnID;
    this.kanbanId = kanbanId;
    this.outcome = outcome;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.tasks = tasks;
  }
  pendingTasks(): boolean {
    
    let it: number = 0;
    this.tasks.forEach(element => {
      if (
        element.status === TaskStatus.inProgress ||
        element.status === TaskStatus.todo
      ) {
        it++;
      }
    });
    if (it > 0) return true;
    else return false;
  }
}
```

I'm using **ngrx** and **redux** to fetch from Store the initial epics , with the following code:

```
 this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRoot.getEpicByColumnId, { columnId: this.column.id })
    ).subscribe(data => ((this.epics = data)));
```

where  getEpicBYColumId is a selector like this:

```
export const getEpicByColumnId = createSelector(
  selectAll,
  (entities: Epic[], { columnId }: { columnId: string }) =>
    entities.filter(epic => epic.columnId == columnId)
);
```

This is the component code to fetch the Epics

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import { KanbanColumn, createTask } from '../state.model';
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem,
  CdkDrag
} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { State1 } from '../../state';
import { Epic } from '../../epic/epic.model';
import * as fromRoot from '../../epic/epic.selectors';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as fromActions from '../../epic/epic.actions';
import { Update } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Task, TaskStatus } from '../Task';
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
@Component({
  selector: 'anms-kanban-column',
  templateUrl: './kanban-column.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kanban-column.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class KanbanColumnComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() column: KanbanColumn;
  epics: Epic[];
 
  constructor(public store: Store<State1>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
    this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRoot.getEpicByColumnId, { columnId: this.column.id })
    ).subscribe(data => ((this.epics = data)));
  }

     }
  }
  
}
```

That's how I iterate the list of epics in this component and creating a new component Epic to show the specific info of Epics:

```
<anms-epic  [kanbanId]="list" *ngFor="let list of epics">
      </anms-epic>
```

the problem is that when I try to access to this method in the Epic template component using a condicinal ngif

```
 <span *ngIf="epic.pendingTasks()===true;then thenBlock else elseBlock" matBadge="1" matBadgeOverlap="false"></span>
```

Angular returns with error TypeError: "x" is not a function.
Is not possible to call a method function of en entity class in a template of Angular?
Its the problem about how typescript & javascript create objects and functions?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Yes , to fix it I had to add the following line in selector

```
   map(epic=>epic.map(epic=>new Epic(epic['id'],epic['name'],epic['description'],epic['code'],epic['entryDate'],epic['MVPFeatures'],epic['state'], epic['WSJF'],epic['columnID'], epic['kanbanId'], epic['outcome'], epic['owner'],epic['tasks'])))
```

So the method to retrieve the epics ends up like this:

```
this.store.pipe(
      select(fromRoot.getEpicByColumnId, { columnId: this.column.id }),
      map(epic=>epic.map(epic=>new Epic(epic['id'],epic['name'],epic['description'],epic['code'],epic['entryDate'],epic['MVPFeatures'],epic['state'], epic['WSJF'],epic['columnID'], epic['kanbanId'], epic['outcome'], epic['owner'],epic['tasks'])))
    ).subscribe(data => ((this.epics = data)));
```

Comment: please provide the content of your component to know how pendingTasks() is defined

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely you are not actually creating Epic class instances. If you are just asserting type with `entities: Epic[]` they won't become `Epic` instance

Somewhere in your code, likely where you get the data from the server and before you add it to your store, you should create actual `Epic` instances.

Something like this will loop through all the response data and create `Epic` instances

```js
this.http.get('someEpicURL').pipe(map(response => response.epics.map(epic => new Epic(epic))))
```

Comment: this is how I create an epic to the Store:
```                                           
 const Epic = this.form.value;

      this.store.dispatch(new fromActions.UpsertEpic({ Epic }));
```

Comment: yes the idea it's correct. I had to modify the pipe which I use to fetch the epics